# How do I change the position of this element on the ViewController programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I have this code in my ViewController.m but there is no Strobyboard/XIB file for it which is fine but on the screen the element comes up in the centre automatically. How Do I add a custom position to it?

```
        UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_bgImage];
    [self addSubview:bgImageView];
```

As far as I'm aware I should be able to add CGRectMake code somewhere but I can't figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bgImageView.frame =CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

---

If you want to maintain the previous values:

```
bgImageView.frame =CGRectMake(x,y, bgImageView.frame.sizewidth, bgImageView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Now my code looks like: UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_bgImage];
        bgImageView.frame =CGRectMake(0,0, bgImageView.width, bgImageView.height);
        [self addSubview:bgImageView];

But I get an error: Property 'width' not found on object of type 'UIImageView'

Comment: @Omar Should be `bgImageView.frame.size.width` and `bgImageView.frame.size.height`.

Comment: The width and height is up to you. But if you want to get them, look at @Rick comment.